# Formatting Output File

Tags: powershell, output

I am creating a script to get the uptime / last reboot of a group of PCs read in from a text file.

I can output the results to file, but it keeps repeating the column header which I do not want.  Basically what I would like is to output the first line for the headers and then each line after for the data the data underneath.  The code below repeats the column header to the output file and there are a lot of spaces between the lines.  Would an output to CSV be easier to handle?

Here is my code.  The first `Out-File` command is to overwrite the file if it exists, essentially clearing the file.

```psh
$computers = Get-Content "c:\temp\ps\pc.txt"

out-file -FilePath "C:\temp\ps\output.txt"
foreach ($computer in $computers) 
{
    $Computerobj = "" | select ComputerName, Uptime, LastReboot
    $wmi = Get-WmiObject -ComputerName $computer -Query "SELECT LastBootUpTime     FROM Win32_OperatingSystem"
    $now = Get-Date
    $boottime = $wmi.ConvertToDateTime($wmi.LastBootUpTime)
    $uptime = $now - $boottime
    $d =$uptime.days
    $h =$uptime.hours
    $m =$uptime.Minutes
    $s = $uptime.Seconds
    $Computerobj.ComputerName = $computer
    $Computerobj.Uptime = "$d Days $h Hours $m Min $s Sec"
    $Computerobj.LastReboot = $boottime
    $Computerobj
    out-file -FilePath "C:\temp\ps\output.txt" -in $computerobj -append
}
```

Answer (score 3):

A pipeline with `ForEach-Object` and `Export-Csv` would be a better approach:

```psh
$now = Get-Date

Get-Content -Path 'C:\temp\ps\pc.txt' | ForEach-Object {
  $wmi = Get-WmiObject -ComputerName $_ -Class Win32_OperatingSystem
  $boottime = $wmi.ConvertToDateTime($wmi.LastBootUpTime)
  $uptime = $now - $boottime
  New-Object -Type PSObject -Property @{
    'ComputerName' = $_
    'Uptime'       = '{0} Days {1} Hours {2} Min {3} Sec' -f $uptime.Days, 
                     $uptime.Hours, $uptime.Minutes, $uptime.Seconds
    'LastReboot'   = $boottime
  }
} | Export-Csv -Path 'C:\temp\ps\output.txt' -NoType
```

If you need the data both in a file and on the console, you could use `ConvertTo-Csv` and `Tee-Object`:

```psh
Get-Content 'c:\temp\ps\pc.txt' | ForEach-Object {
  ...
} | ConvertTo-Csv -NoType | Tee-Object -FilePath 'C:\temp\ps\output.txt'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$computers = Get-Content "c:\temp\ps\pc.txt"

#Create a report variable as an array to hold all our data
$report = @();

#No longer necessary
#out-file -FilePath "C:\temp\ps\output.txt"

foreach ($computer in $computers) 
{
    $Computerobj = "" | select ComputerName, Uptime, LastReboot
    $wmi = Get-WmiObject -ComputerName $computer -Query "SELECT LastBootUpTime     FROM Win32_OperatingSystem"
    $now = Get-Date
    $boottime = $wmi.ConvertToDateTime($wmi.LastBootUpTime)
    $uptime = $now - $boottime
    $d =$uptime.days
    $h =$uptime.hours
    $m =$uptime.Minutes
    $s = $uptime.Seconds
    $Computerobj.ComputerName = $computer
    $Computerobj.Uptime = "$d Days $h Hours $m Min $s Sec"
    $Computerobj.LastReboot = $boottime

    #Add the computer to the report array
    $report += $Computerobj
}

#Uncomment this if you need to see the report as well as write it to a file
#Write-Output $report

out-file -FilePath "C:\temp\ps\output.txt" -in $report
```

Now you can manipulate the report as a whole, so you can even add things at the end like `$report = $report | Sort-Object -Property ComputerName` to sort the report by computer names, or filter it with `Where-Object`.